# Multiple get requests in one useEffect (react)

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, get, axios

I have a database of images, each image contains a URL (to the image), and unique ID.

I'm grabbing images by id like so:
fetchData = a function that is responsible for fetching the data with api url

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("/images/1")
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
            setImage(data.data)
        })
}, [])
```

However, in one of my components I need go grab 3 different images (id: 1, 4, 10).
I can obviously do it via 3 different useEffects but that seems wrong.

Also, I I tried grabbing all images

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("/images/")
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
            setImages(data.data)
        })
}, [])
```

then doing `<img src ={images[1].url}` but that also doesn't seem like the best solution as I'm grabbing all the images (there is a lot of them).

Any tips on how to make this as clean as possible?

Comment: If you have acces to the backend part , may be it could be interesting to add a route to fetch images by an array of id. Or an other solution is to filter your imageList by their id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom hook:

```
function useImage(id) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("/images/" + id)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data => setImage(data.data))
  }, [])

  return image
}
```

...and then use it as many times as you need in your component:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const image1 = useImage('1')
  const image2 = useImage('2')
  const image3 = useImage('3')

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image1.url} />
      <img src={image2.url} />
      <img src={image3.url} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would create a custom component responsible only for grabbing and displaying the image, and use it three times.

```js
function ImageComponent({ id }) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // In case of id changed, reset component state
    setImage(undefined);
    
    fetchData(`/images/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data => {
        setImage(data.data)
      })
  }, [id]);

  return (
    // Do something with the data here
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Promise.all to make all the fetching in one useEffect, if that is your goal.

```
const imageIds = ["1", "20", "300"];

Promise.all(imageIds.map(id => fetchData(`/images/${id}`).then(res => res.data)))
  .then(imageDataArray => {
    // do what you want with the images
    console.log(imageDataArray);
  });
```